# If I create and insert a user within test method, does it affect Salesforce user licenses?

Tags: unit-test, user

I know that users are not considered as data in test classes. For example, I can still fetch a user from database, even if the test has `SeeAllData=false` annotation.

How about creating and inserting a user within a test method? Does it affect licensing? Can user inserts be freely used within tests or that's something that should be avoided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not affect the licensing as any data created within a test is deleted after the test has finished running. See a great article here http://scox67.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/unit-testing-tips-tricks-part-1.html?m=1 The part that will apply to you is Tip #4 on how to create users and use them using runAs() method.

If you need any help implementing let me know

Answer (score 2):

I have had test classes fail due to not having sufficient free licenses available when`SeeAllData=true` while creating new users, but *not* when `SeeAllData=false`, both when needing to create a RunAs user and other users, such as Owners or community users.